# S5 required to enter Google pw for factory reset. Only allowing me to input 15 characters. Pw is 32 char

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

I am attempting to do a factory reset on a Galaxy S5. On the confirmation screen, it is requiring me to input my Google password. I am only able to enter 15 characters on this screen. My Google password is 32 characters.

How do I bypass this?

Comment: Why not do a Factory Reset from the recovery menu (Power on + Volume up buttons) as suggested in the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it's asking for Google password, then you can [change your Google password online](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41078?hl=en) for now to something shorter.

But, i believe that it doesn't ask for Google password, rather it wants your lock screen password or a special password, that you have set up under settings>security>factory reset data password.

Another option is to do a [factory reset using hard keys](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/factory-reset-galaxy-s5/) but if you do decide to go with that option, then don't change your Google password before doing it, otherwise you might be locked out of your device.